# Bind DataTable to a DataGrid

Tags: c#

I've created this code to fill three DataGrids with data from other three DataTable. The first and the last work perfect. The problem is with the second DataGrid. When I bind it to the `DT_Clientes` (the second DataTable) and try to edit anything from the second DataGrid, the program return an error that say that the Index must be more than 0.

```
#region GRUPOS
SQL = "select descricao from grupos;";
command = new FbCommand(SQL, Connection);
Connection.Open();
FbDataAdapter adapter = new FbDataAdapter(command);
DT_Grupos = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(DT_Grupos);
Connection.Close();

#region AJUSTANDO DATAGRID
Dgv_Rel01_Grupo.ItemsSource = DT_Grupos.DefaultView;
Dgv_Rel01_Grupo.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;
Dgv_Rel01_Grupo.Columns[0].Header = "Grupos";
Dgv_Rel01_Grupo.Columns[0].Width = 295;
#endregion
#endregion

#region CLIENTES
SQL = "select codigo, nome from cliente where situacao = 'Ativo' order by codigo asc;";
command = new FbCommand(SQL, Connection);
Connection.Open();
adapter = new FbDataAdapter(command);
DT_Clientes = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(DT_Clientes);
Connection.Close();

#region AJUSTANDO DATAGRID
Dgv_Rel03_Clientes.ItemsSource = DT_Clientes.DefaultView;
Dgv_Rel03_Clientes.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;
Dgv_Rel03_Clientes.Columns[0].Width = 50;
Dgv_Rel03_Clientes.Columns[1].Width = 360;
#endregion
#endregion

#region FORNECEDORES
SQL = "select codigo, nome from fornecedor where situacao = 'Ativo' order by codigo asc;";
command = new FbCommand(SQL, Connection);
Connection.Open();
adapter = new FbDataAdapter(command);
DT_Fornecedores = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(DT_Fornecedores);
Connection.Close();

#region AJUSTANDO DATAGRID
Dgv_Rel01_Fornecedor.ItemsSource = DT_Fornecedores.DefaultView;
Dgv_Rel01_Fornecedor.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;
Dgv_Rel01_Fornecedor.Columns[0].Header = "Código";
Dgv_Rel01_Fornecedor.Columns[1].Header = "Razão Social";
Dgv_Rel01_Fornecedor.Columns[0].Width = 50;
Dgv_Rel01_Fornecedor.Columns[1].Width = 280;
#endregion
#endregion
```

I tested change `Datagrid.ItemsSource` for `Datagrid.DataContext` but it didn't work. I checked the DataGrid after running this code and there's no column in it, even showing the data from my DataTable.

Comment: The second query is not returning any data.  If you are using SQL Server use SQL Server Management Studio and verify the query to make sure data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the problems is here:

```
SQL = "select codigo, nome from cliente where situacao = 'Ativo' order by codigo asc;";
```

This query is not returning any data, which means there is no `situacao` who's value is `Ativo`. You should try and run this query directly in your database and see if it fetch any result, probably it'll not.